# Why don't I have permission to cd to a partition on my SD card?

Tags: raspbian

I added a FAT32 "DATA" partition at the end of my 8GB SD card to be able to directly transfer data to it via an SD-Card-Reader under Windows.

If I boot Raspbian to Desktop, i can access this partition. If I boot to Terminal and log in as "pi" I do not have permission to even `cd` to the partition. I can `cd` to /media/ and `ls` shows me that "DATA" is there.

Do I have to add rights for the "pi" user? But then again, I thought that you are logged in as "pi" in the Desktop environment as well.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l media`?, and how have you mounted the partition?

Comment: @Wilf indeed! desktop: "drwx........ 58 pi pi [...] DATA", terminal: "drwx........ 2 root root [...] DATA". I did not do anything regarding the mounting of the partition, it is already mounted after boot. So how to automatically give rights for pi when booting to terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turned out that the partition is mounted for the user pi when raspbian is booted to desktop but not when it is booted into terminal.

to do this, edit the file `/etc/fstab` -- for me it was enough to add the line
`/dev/<deviceID>  /media/DATA      vfat    defaults      0         0`

this mounts the DATA partition during boot. you might have to replace `defaults` by more specific parameters -- see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fstab) for example.